# Magento 2 V1/carts/mine/totals API getting Old data

Tags: magento2, api

In magento 2, after add to cart or merge cart when i am call V1/carts/mine/totals API first time it send me old data. After i am calling same API it give me right data that available in Quote table.

anyone have idea why this happen ?